# Proof: If no prime less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$ divides $n$, then $n$ is a prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, factoring

I have the following theorem:

> If no prime less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$ divides $n$, then $n$ is a prime.

And the following proof (proof by contradiction) for said theorem:

> Suppose that no prime less than or equal to $\sqrt{n}$ divides $n$ but $n = ab$, with neither $a$ nor $b$ equal to $1$.
>
> Now $a$ and $b$ cannot both be strictly larger than $\sqrt{n}$ or their product would be larger than $n$.
>
> So one of $a$ or $b$ is not larger than $\sqrt{n}$: assume (without loss of generality) that $a \le \sqrt{n}$.
>
> Now $a$ cannot be prime (as we have assumed $n$ has no prime factor this small), and so is composite.
>
> Therefore $a$ has a prime factor $p$, which must be less than $a$.
>
> But then $p < a \le \sqrt{n}$ is a prime factor of $n$, and this contradicts our hypothesis.
>
> Hence $n$ is prime.

We deduce that $a$ is composite. But why does this then mean that $a$ has a prime factor $p$? So this is saying that all composite numbers have a prime factor? Why?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

PostScript: I am assuming that [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_number) is the definition of composite number being used here.

Comment: Any integer, composite or not, which is greater than $1$ has prime factors. Is this not obvious to you?

Comment: @Arthur You're totally right. I never work with prime numbers, so this wasn't something that I was thinking of at all.

Comment: @Arthur As this is a rather elementary proof, it feels wrong to presume knowledge like this.

Comment: @Sudix Maybe. It's not very difficult to prove, though. The smallest divisor $a$ (apart from $1$) of any given natural number $n>1$ has to be prime because the divisors of $a$ will also be divisors of $n$, and $n$ has no divisors smaller than $a$, so $a$ can't have any divisors smaller than $a$ either.

Comment: @Arthur True, it's not difficult to prove once you know the general proof techniques to reach your aim. I would have used infinite descend, but your proof fits in with the proof above a lot more nicely. Let's hope OP takes the time to integrate your proof into the one above, because that way he gets a satisfying answer to his question (unlike in the answer that's linked, or the answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have assumed $a>1$ (See the first line) and we have show it cannot be prime (otherwise $n$ has a prime factor $\leq\sqrt n$).

Typically, the definition of composite is that the number can be written as the product of more than one prime (that is, is greater than $1$ and isn’t prime). This follows from the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic).